# Cant get QtVSAddin to work with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

So I am following the directions provided by Qt project website, http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtVSAddin and I am on the last step which reads,

"Open the Qt4VS2003\Qt4VSAddin folder, and copy Qt5VSAddin.AddIn and the Release directory to your VS Addins folder – by default this is “%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Addins”, but this can be changed under Tools->Options->Environment->Add-in Security. Rename Release to something meaningful (like Qt5VSAddin, since it goes with the addin).

Open Qt5VSAddin.AddIn in your favorite text editor, and find the Version tag. Change it to the version appropriate for your VS version – 2008 is 9.0, 2010 is 10.0, and 2012 is 11.0. Find the Assembly tag and change it to reflect the location of the Qt5VSAddin.dll file within the binary folder, i.e. Qt5VSAddin\Qt5VSAddin.dll.

Go back to Visual Studio, and open Tools->Add-in Manager.

My first question is it refers to "binary folder" and Qt5VSAddin.dll? Not sure exactly what they are refering to, but I found Qt5VSAddin.dll in my Debug folder. For some reason the instructions make it seem like it should of automatically been put in my Realease folder...but it was not. Either way, I copied the one found in the Debug folder to same directory, and also tried to copy it to the release directory we renamed(following the directions) however when I go to Tools->Add-in Manager and select my Qt Add on I get that the system cannot find the file specified, error 8007002. It doesn't state which file it cant find, but I would assume its the .dll...which is clearly there....any ideas?

Comment: Just in case, you are not using the express version? I do not understand why you mix Qt 4 and 5 though.

Comment: I would expect Qt to be a dependency. Although dependency walker should help.